# How to create a Flutter plugin that works in another Flutter project?

Tags: plugins, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-plugin

I have a Flutter plugin successfully running on my newly created Flutter-plugin project. And both worlds, iOS and Android, are able to run the example/lib/main.dart example-code of this Flutter-plugin successfully.

However, once I try to use the plugin in another Flutter project, that's when things crash.

So far, I have tried two ways of how to integrate my self-written plugin into another Flutter project:

Inside my Flutter project (the one I try to use the plugin inside), I go to the `pubspec.yaml` file and I write:

I tried ...local path integration:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  my_plugin_name:
    path: ../../../Flutter_plugins/my_plugin_name/
```

or I tried ...remote integration:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  my_plugin_name:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/XXXX/my_plugin_name.git
```

Both integrations work fine and VSCode seem to import the plugin correctly !

BUT THIS IS WHERE THINGS CRASH!! AS SOON AS I ADD ANYTHING TO THE `dependencies`, THAT IS WHEN THINGS CRASH AFTERWARDS.

To test if it works, I open my Flutter project and I go to lib/main.dart:

And inside lib/main.dart of the project I want to integrate the plugin into, I write pretty much the same as was written in the plugin-example folder of the plugin-project (see code further down).

Or in other words, I try to run exactly the same code that was given by the plugin-example folder, but this time inside my other Flutter project having the plugin imported.

I therefore paste the example-code into my lib/main.dart file of my Flutter project.

Inside main.dart, I add the following imports:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:my_plugin_name/my_plugin_name.dart';
```

.
And the code pasted into main.dart:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String _platformVersion = 'Unknown';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initPlatformState();
  }

  // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    String platformVersion;
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      platformVersion = await MyPluginNameClass.getVersion;
    } on PlatformException {
      platformVersion = 'Failed to get platform version.';
    }
    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
    // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
    // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _platformVersion = platformVersion;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('$_platformVersion\n'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The compiler does not give me any error or warning at this point. All seems fine.

HOWEVER, IF I BUILD AND RUN, I GET ERROR EXCEPTIONS FOR BOTH WORLDS, IOS AND ANDROID - WHY ?????

On iOS, the error messages are:

```
2018-12-23 14:32:52.179 xcodebuild[56661:1181076] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID D76765677-CB11-4D25-A34B-E33DB5A7C231 for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/KZLinkedConsole.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2018-12-23 14:32:52.179 xcodebuild[56661:1181076] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID D76765677-CB11-4D25-A34B-E33DB5A7C231 for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/ColorSenseRainbow.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2018-12-23 14:32:52.179 xcodebuild[56661:1181076] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID D76765677-CB11-4D25-A34B-E33DB5A7C231 for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/BBUDebuggerTuckAway.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2018-12-23 14:32:52.180 xcodebuild[56661:1181076] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID D76765677-CB11-4D25-A34B-E33DB5A7C231 for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/Alcatraz.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
=== BUILD TARGET sqflite OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
/Users/user/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/git/my_plugin_name-5cc22b5c6d2345ba1ab23a44324b222c68d24ab4/ios/Classes/MyPluginName.m:2:9: fatal error: 'my_plugin_name/my_plugin_name-Swift.h' file not found
#import < my_plugin_name/my_plugin_name-Swift.h>
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone XS.
Exited (sigterm)
```

(...I already tried `flutter clean` or `pod update` as was mentioned in other stackoverflow entries - but no change on the error...)

On Android, the error messages are:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> Execution of compression failed.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 25s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Does anybody have any clue on what to do here ?

What do I miss when integrating a local or remote Flutter-plugin ?

Comment: The problem is actually related to the dependencies within the platform sources. In the iOS it can’t find the `my_plugin_name-Swift.h` file.

Comment: Your import and the error has a space in it too. `#import < my_plugin_name/my_plugin_name-Swift.h>`

Comment: The space was a copy/paste error. In my original import, there is everything correct... Still having problems anyway with the non-spaced code...

Comment: (I corrected the space that Clemens pointed out to me). But turns out that as soon as I add the `dependencies` (either as `path:` or as `git:`) that is when things go corrupt. What do I have to do in order to make the flutter project still compile when adding a dependency ?? (i.e. there is tow spaces for each new line since this seem to matter as well in `pubspec.yaml`...). What do I do wrong here ??

Comment: The discussions in   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16049 
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21096
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16036  might help

Comment: Hmm, no they don't really help. I've seen these discussions before but I don't know which of the 1000 tricks they describe applies to my hello world example.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out that not the plugin-adding is the problem!

It is rather my large asset that I have inside the Flutter app that causes the exception.

And it must be more or less a coincidence that my Flutter app crashes from the moment I add the plugin to my app. It was misleading. (I therefore assume that the exception might have happened as well - later when I build-up my Flutter app and add more code. It might be a memory issue of some sort...or you tell me!)

As soon as I remove my large asset (665 MB), the plugin integration works smoothly without any exception.

The question shifts tough to another `StackOverflow` question: [How to integrate a large asset in my Flutter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53922122/how-do-i-integrate-a-large-asset-in-my-flutter-app)

And this query can be closed.